# Django using sessions and cookies in the same view function

Tags: django, django-views, session-cookies, django-sessions

I'm trying to set the cookies and use the sessions as well but when I set the cookies, it doesn't detect the cookies on the website. I don't know what I did wrong so help me out please. Thanks.

view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def session(request):
    num_visits = request.session.get('num_visits', 0) + 1
    request.session['num_visits'] = num_visits
    resp = HttpResponse('View Count=' +str(num_visits) + ' e78e39ea')
    resp.set_cookie('dj4e_cookie', 'e78e39ea', max_age=1000)
    resp.set_cookie('zap', 42)
    return HttpResponse(resp)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.session),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the response, not wrap it in *another* response:

```
def session(request):
    num_visits = request.session.get('num_visits', 0) + 1
    request.session['num_visits'] = num_visits
    resp = HttpResponse(f'View Count={num_visits} e78e39ea')
    resp.set_cookie('dj4e_cookie', 'e78e39ea', max_age=1000)
    resp.set_cookie('zap', 42)
    return resp  # ← return the response itself
```